# Perl regex working in online PCRE tester but not in perl command

Tags: html, regex, bash, perl, pcre

I've written the following PCRE regex to strip scripts from HTML pages: `<script.*?>[\s\S]*?< *?\/ *?script *?>`

It works on many online PCRE regex testers:

https://regex101.com/r/lsxyI6/1

https://www.regextester.com/?fam=102647

It does **NOT** work when I run the following perl substitution command in a bash terminal: `cat tmp.html | perl -pe 's/<script.*?>[\s\S]*?< *?\/ *?script *?>//g'`

I am using the following test data:

```
<script>
                       $(document).ready(function() {
                           var url = window.location.href;
                           var element = $('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
                               if (url.charAt(url.length - 1) == '/') {
                                   url = url.substring(0, url.length - 1);
                               }

                               return this.href == url;
                           }).parent();

                           if (element.is('li')) {
                               element.addClass('active');
                           }
                       });
                   </script>
```

**P.S.** I am using regex to parse HTML because the HTML parser I am forced to use (xmlpath) breaks when there are complex scripts on the page. I am using this regex to remove scripts from the page before passing it to the parser.

Comment: By default the perl command line read a file line by line, if you want to change this behaviour, you have to switch the slurp mode on. However I suggest to find an other way to parse your html.

Comment: Btw, what's wrong with simple `/<script.*?script\s*>//` ?

Comment: @zdim It would probably work fine, I just don't have much experience with regex and didn't consider that. Thanks!

Comment: `[\s\S]` can be written as `.` -- `[\s\S]` is the set of all space and non-space characters.

Comment: `[\s\S]` can be written as `.` if and only if `/s` or equivalent is used.

Comment: The repeated uses of `.*?` can cause major problems. You want `perl -0777pe's{<script[^>]*>(?:(?!</script[^>]*>).))*</script[^>]*>}{}sg'`

Comment: Note that it's very easy to circumvent your "protections" (even with my change).

Comment: @nulldev - out of curiousity, how are you planning to "reconstitute" the file once you've run your parser on the actual html?  Or is the html parsing read-only?

Comment: @zzxyz I don't have to reconstitute the file, I'm parsing it as read-only.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for the help. Also, I'm not actually using this as protection, I'm just using this to avoid crashing the parser. The script I'm running this in is only invoked explicitly under a watchful human eye. It's never run automatically and the output is never "evaled" or anything similar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to tell perl not to break up each line of the file into its own separate record with `-0`.

```
 perl -0 -pe 's/<script.*?>[\s\S]*?< *?\/ *?script *?>//g' tmp.html
```

This actually tells perl to break up records on `'\0'`.  `perl -0777` will very explicitly slurp the whole file.

Comment: You mean not to break the file into separate records (lines) ?

Comment: That was fast, I was total unaware that perl processed files line-by-line. I'll accept this answer in a couple minutes, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

By the way, because I find slurping whole files distasteful, and because I don't care what html has to say about line breaks...a quicker, cleaner, more correct way to do this **IF** you can guarantee there is no important content on `<script>` tag lines is:

```
perl -ne 'print if !(/<script>/../<\/script>/)' tmp.html
```

(modifying the two regexes to your fancy, of course)
`..` is a stateful operator that is flipped on by the expression before it being true and off by the one after being true.

```
~/test£ cat example.html
<important1/>
<edgecase1/><script></script><edgecase2/>
<important2/>
<script></script>
<important3/>
<script>
<notimportant/>
</script>

~/test£ perl -ne 'print if !(/<script>/../<\/script>/)' example.html
<important1/>
<important2/>
<important3/>
```

And to (mostly) address content on script tag lines but outside tags:

```
~/test£ perl -ne 'print if !(/<script>/../<\/script>/);print "$1\n" if /(.+)<script>/;print "$1\n" if /<\/script>(.+)/;' example.html
<important1/>
<edgecase1/>
<edgecase2/>
<important2/>
<important3/>
```

Comment: @EdwardKirton It will

Comment: (because `..` keeps state)

Comment: Thanks for the added explanation, zzxyz.  Very nice.