# Remove newline from the text between parentheses

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to remove newline character from parentheses.

```
lorum (ip
sum) dolor
```

So the output would be

```
lorum (ipsum) dolor
```

I am able to select text inside parentheses using regex pattern below but not able to remove newline.

```
\((.*?)\)
```

I tried `\(([\n\r]*?)\)` but no luck.

Comment: Yes in web browser.

Comment: a simple \n will help you. refer this https://regex101.com/r/8XWPrW/1/

Comment: @user3783243 it is newline character `\n`. Line break only appears in browser view:srouce. I can fix that with `echo str_replace("\n", '', $data);`. It is being applied on the whole data string. My goal is to replace newline character only if it is inside parentheses. Makes sense?

Comment: @AZee yes right... I have updated my regex in my answer. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/51182539/1262248

Comment: @user3783243 it is 1 new line character only.

Comment: Then in that case the answer below should work for you. To explain why your regex failed though... your `[\n\r]*` would have worked fine to find the new lines, but there are other characters inside the parenthesis so you need to check for those as well.

Comment: @user3783243 so are you saying that my regex is only selecting newline and carriage return. It is not checking/returning the other characters?

Comment: For `\(([\n\r]*?)\)` to match you'd need the string to be `(\n)` or `(\n\r)` or any number of new line/return characters. You have more than that in the parenthesis though.

Comment: @user3783243 got it! thank you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below regex:

```
(.*\(.*?)(?:\n)(.*?\).*)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/8XWPrW/4/

Test String:

```
lorum (ip
sum) dolor

lorum ip
sum dolor
```

After substitution:

```
lorum (ipsum) dolor

lorum ip
sum dolor
```

Also, as required, it will only detect new line when it is within parentheses

-- EDIT--

As discussed in the comments, it will work fine with `preg_replace` as well. It's just the groups needs to be mentioned

PHP code:

```
$data="lorum (ip
sum) dolor

lorum ip
sum dolor";
echo preg_replace("'(.*?\(.*?)(?:\n)(.*?\).*)'", "$1$2", $data);
```

Comment: When I use this regex pattern in `preg_replace("/(.*\(.*?)(?:\n)(.*?\).*)/", "", $data)` it removes everything including the text inside parentheses. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @AZee You need to use the first and second capture groups in the replacement as Aman did in the regex101 example. (SO should have the full answer, hopefully Aman updates)

Comment: Yes I understand it now. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

I found this answer very useful, but found it tricky to implement Aman's answer on the command line. In case others find this page searching to do the same, the solution was:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/(.*{{.*?)(?:\n)(.*?}}.*)/\1\2/g'
```

(I was assisted by [zzxyz's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49037352))